# Mapping Model Data in MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

**Background:** In my dotnet MVC project, I have two data model classes

```
public class IenState
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public ulong NetId { get; set; }
   public ushort NodeId { get; set; } 
   .
   .
   public ushort SyncDomId { get; set; }
}

public class IenConfig
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public ulong NetId { get; set; }
   public ushort NodeId { get; set; } 
}
```

and database context

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    ---
    ---
    public DbSet<Models.IenState> IenStateDb { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Models.IenConfig> IenConfig { get; set; }
}
```

**Question:**
In the controller 'GET Edit/id' action method, I want to read an item from **IenStateDb** table and but return view as an **IenConfig** item. The client then can change some or all items (except the 'Id' field). The updated item is then stored in **IenConigDb** table via **POST: Edit/id**  method. I **want to find out the most efficient way to do the work in the Edit method**. Currently I am doing it as follows:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var ienState = await _context.IenStateDb.FindAsync(id);
        if (ienState == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        //Map IenState to IenConfig model object
        IenConfig ienConfig = new IenConfig();

        ienConfig.Id = ienState.Id;
        ienConfig.NetId = ienState.NetId;            
        ienConfig.NodeId = ienState.NodeId;

        return View(ienConfig);
    }
```

All this works, but I am not sure whether this is a good approach. The number of parameters in **IenConfig** is a subset of what is in **IenState**, but otherwise they could be quite large.

Comment: 1. You should return a ViewModel classes to View, not entity class. 2. You can use AutoMapper for mapping objects.

Comment: I have corresponding Views class for IenConfig model. I will try out the AutoMapper.

Answer (score 0):

The efficient way is you can use `Automapper` [Automapper documentation](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html). 
AutoMapper is an `open source library present in GitHub`. To install the library, first install the `NuGet Package Manager in your Visual Studio`. Once you installed the NuGet package manager, open the NuGet console and enter the following command to install the AutoMapper library:

```
PM>  Install-Package AutoMapper
```

find below create the mapping between two object types "IenState" and "IenConfig"

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IenConfig, IenState>();
```

here you will get the mapped instance of IenConfig as IenState

```
var IenConfig = Mapper.Map<IenConfig, IenState>(person);
```

Comment: Thanks for details on how to use the AutoMapper.  I will try it out, and frankly I am new to all these tools.